# Custom MKAnnotationView location drastically changes when rotate or zoom in/out of map

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I've got two custom `MKAnnotationViews`, which display fine when they are initially added to the `MKMapView`.

The issue is, when rotating, or zooming out, their drawn locations seem to become more and more off. To reiterate, the closer I zoom in, the more accurate they appear, but when zooming out and rotating they are completely off. Any ideas?

Looks good (initial state):

[image: First image]

Looks bad (and wrong):

[image: Second image]

My `viewForAnnotation` method is pretty basic, nothing fancy going on here.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {


        if let annotation = annotation as? PKDriverAnnotation
            {
            let identifier = "driver"
            var annotationView: PKDriverAnnotationView
            if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) { // 2
                dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
                annotationView = dequeuedView as! PKDriverAnnotationView
            } else {
                // 3
                annotationView = PKDriverAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                annotationView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PKTransactionMapViewController.annotationViewTapped(recognizer:))))
            }

            self.driverAnnotationView = annotationView

            return annotationView
        } else if let annotation = annotation as? PKAnnotation {
            let identifier = "pin"
            var view: MKAnnotationView
            if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) { // 2
                dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
                view = dequeuedView
            } else {
                // 3
                view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                view.image = UIImage(named: "TransactionAnnotation")
                view.canShowCallout = false
                view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PKHomeViewController.annotationViewTapped(recognizer:))))

                let profilePic = FBSDKProfilePictureView(frame: CGRect(x: 4, y: 4, width: 43, height: 43))
                profilePic.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: profilePic.center.y)
                profilePic.profileID = self.transaction!.availableParking.holder.fbid
                profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = 21.0
                profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
                view.addSubview(profilePic)
            }

            return view
        }
        return nil
    }
```

## Update

I suspected this was somewhat related to anchor points, and I was able to fix the "parking pin annotation views" rotation by `view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)`, but had no luck with driver annotation view (the one w/ the car)

Appreciate the help SO!

Answer (score 2):

You should set the [`centerOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/1452144-centeroffset) of your `MKAnnotationView`. As the documentation says:

> By default, the center point of an annotation view is placed at the coordinate point of the associated annotation. You can use this property to reposition the annotation view as needed. This x and y offset values are measured in points. Positive offset values move the annotation view down and to the right, while negative values move it up and to the left.

Comment: For the driver annotation view, I believe the coordinate point should be the center of the view, since its place within a square and spans the whole view, thus how would changing the center offset help? For the pin annotation view, I was able to resolve with the anchor point adjustment mentioned in the update.

Comment: I would not change anchor points. This is the purpose of `centerOffset`.

Comment: Ok, so lets say my driver annotation view is 100 x 100 points, you would make the centerOffset 0,50?

Comment: 0, -50 to shift it up, I believe.

Comment: the cars front is at the top so down would seem more sensible?

Comment: Sure. I was focusing on the pin. Yep, if you want to move the car down, you’d use positive number.

Comment: as suspected, this didn't fix the issue, merely just offset the frame of the view by y.

Comment: Yeah, the `centerPoint` change would affect the location of the annotation view with respect to the annotation’s `coordinate`, if the annotation view wasn't quite centered appropriately. But if you’re seeing radical change of `coordinate`, then there’s something else going on, too. I’d suspect something going on with the annotation itself (e.g. are you instantisting a new annotation object each time? or are you referencing some property that may get be mutating on us?). We may need to see some annotation code, as I don’t see anything obviously wrong in the `viewFor` code.

Comment: By the way, I might suggest commenting out the whole `viewFor` method and rely upon standard annotation views. That will confirm whether the behavior is this method or something going on with the annotations themselves.